# 1D biased random walk - is the event of infinte many returns a tail event?

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

I am considering a biased random walk:

$X_1,X_2,\dots$ iid with $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1=-1)=1-p$ with $p\in[0,1]\backslash\{1/2\}$, $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$.

In this setting I want to examine the event $A=\{S_n=0$ infinitely often$\}$. 
I suppose that $\mathbb{P}(A)=1$ or at least $\mathbb{P}(A)\in\{0,1\}$  but I can't prove it.

My attempts are towards Borel-Cantelli or Kolmogorov 0-1.
Using Kolmogorov I should try to prove that this is a tail event and that's my problem. One can rewrite $A$ as the $\text{limsup }A_n$ with $A_n=\{S_n=0\}$ but now I am a bit lost.
I would appreciate any hints (Is this a tail event at all?, Is it correct that $\mathbb{P}(A)\in\{0,1\}$?, $\dots$).
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should check Hewitt–Savage zero–one law - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hewitt%E2%80%93Savage_zero%E2%80%93one_law

Comment: The event A is not a tail event and its probability is P(A)=0, a fact which can be proven using the strong law of large numbers.

Comment: Thank you both. The Hewitt-Savage was quite interesting to discover. Great idea!
I did prove P(A)=0 using Borel-Cantelli and the ratio-test.

How can I close this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use Borel-Cantelli. First note that $\mathbb{P}(S_{2m+1}=0)=0~\forall m$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(S_{2k}=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{2n \choose n}p^n(1-p)^n.$$
We get (in order to use the ratio test) $$\text{limsup}_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{{2n \choose n}p^n(1-p)^n}=\text{limsup }_{n\to\infty}p(1-p)\sqrt[n]{\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}}=4p(1-p).$$
This is less than $1$ iff $p(1-p)<\frac{1}{4}$ which is the case by definition of $p$. Hence by the ratio test, the sum converges and Borel-Cantelli leads to $$\mathbb{P}(\text{limsup}_{n\to\infty}\{S_{2k=0}\})=\mathbb{P}(A)=0.$$

Comment: We can also compute directly $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}p^n(1-p)^n = 1/|1-2p|-1$.